# Java sorting by quantity of letters

Tags: java, sorting

I'm new in Java. And I have the task in Java sorting word by quantity of letters and using StringBuilder and without using Java collections. For example `hhhheeeeelllo` it should be like this `eeeeehhhhlllo` and working with other word. And I have this for example `hhhhhhheeeeeelllllllllo` console shows me this `hhhhhheeeeeehlllllllllo`. I know how must looks like in C++. But I tried to rewrite it in Java and nothing. Please help me.

I know that I must use this loop for example

```
for(int i = 1; i<s.length(); i++) {
   for(int j = s.length()-1; j>=i; j--) {
      if(word[j-1] > word[j]) {
        ....
     }
   }
}
```

And this is my code:

```
 class StringBuilder {
     public void sorting_stringBuilder(String s) {
         int i,j;
         //String r="";
         //char c;
         char temp;
         java.lang.StringBuilder news = new java.lang.StringBuilder(s);

         for(i=1; i<s.length(); i++) {
            //c = news.charAt(i);

            for(j=s.length() - 1; j >= i; j--) {

               //c = news.charAt(i);
               if((int) news.charAt(j-1) > (int) news.charAt(j)) {
                   //c = news.charAt(j);
                   temp = news.charAt(i);
                   news.setCharAt(i, news.charAt(j-1));
                   news.setCharAt(j-1, temp);
               }
            }
           //r=r + c;
         }
         //System.out.println(r);
         System.out.println("s is = "+news);
     }
 }

 public class Laba3 {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
         sb.sorting_stringBuilder("hhhhhhheeeeeelllllllllo");
     }
 }
```

Comment: Would you please first of all clarify what you try to do. What is exactly "sorting word by quantity of letters"? Maybe with a couple of examples.
Also what does "and nothing" means? If it does not work, describe, how exactly does not it work.

Comment: From reading what you have said, so you mean that this: `abcbccc` should become `ccccbba`?

Comment: @lexicore for example `hhhheeeeelllo` it should be like this `eeeeehhhhlllo` and working with other word. And I have this for example `hhhhhhheeeeeelllllllllo` console shows me this `hhhhhheeeeeehlllllllllo`

Comment: @jrtapsell yes `ccccbba`

Comment: @Lado Ok, I more or less get it. But where do you actually count characters in your code? I don't really understand how you implement it.

Comment: @lexicore it starting from if

Comment: @Lado No, you don't count characters there. You just compare two characters by their code.

Comment: It is advisable to avoid naming your classes the same as classes in the Java API (StringBuilder is a very commonly used Java class).

Comment: @lexicore no I mean after `if(...)` I copy elements into `temp` and in  `setCharAt()` I tried to  swap letters

Comment: @Lado If you are not counting characters in your code the your code does not solve the problem you've described. It is incorrect then and it makes no sense to discuss why you actually get wrong results.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do it:

- First, count characters, for instance using a `Map`.
- Next, sort the `Map` on counts.
- Finally simply iterate the sorted entries and append each character the "count" times to the `StringBuilder`.

Something along the lines (I'll just type the code here so probably won't even compile):

```
// Input string
String s = ... ;
Map<Character, AtomicInteger> countOfCharacters = new HashMap<>();
char[] characters = s.toCharArray();
// Count the characters
for (char c : character) {
    countOfCharacters.computeIfAbsent(c, new AtomicInteger()).incrementAndGet();
}
// Get the char/count entries
Set<Map.Entry<Character, AtomicInteger>> countOfCharacterEntries =
    countOfCharacters.entrySet();
// Convert to array
Map.Entry<Character, AtomicInteger> countOfCharacterArray =
    new Map.Entry<Character, AtomicInteger>[countOfCharacterEntries.size()];
countOfCharacterEntries.toArray(countOfCharacterArray);
// Sort
Arrays.sort(countOfCharacterArray,
    Comparator.comparing(entry -> entry.getValue().get());
// Output to a StringBuilder
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (Map.Entry<Character, AtomicInteger> countOfCharacter: countOfCharacterArray) {
   char c = countOfCharacter.getKey().charValue();
   int count = countOfCharacter.getValue().get();
   for(int index = 0; index < count; index++) {
       sb.append(c);
   }
}
return sb.toString();
```

Comment: thank you very much. I will try to use it and rewrite it. But I can't use any things like map or other things(this rules in my task). Everything by "hand".

Comment: @Lado You should pretty please with sugar on top write ALL of your constraints for the problem BEFORE people invest time in answers. Eventually recalling an important detail like "I actually cannot use maps" afterwards is not really helpful.

Comment: @Lado It is quite possible to rewrite it without maps. You can count integers directly in an array.

Answer (score 0):

the easiest and linear approach (not using any libraries):

```
    public static void main (String [] args) {
    String input = "hhhheeeeelllo";// it should be like this eeeeehhhhlllo

    final char[] alphabet = new char[256]; // assumming ascii characters only

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        alphabet[input.charAt(i)]++;
    }

    StringBuilder sorted = new StringBuilder(input.length());

    for (int i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++) {
        char ch = (char) i;
        for (int j = 0; j < alphabet[i]; j++) {
            sorted.append(ch);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(sorted.toString());
}
```

Comment: I think your code lacks actually sorting character by count. So your code would still output `abbcccc` for the input `abcbccc`.

Comment: Sorry you are right missed this one :) - suggested by example which was alphabetic.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is to sore letters in a word :

```
String word = "hhhhhhheeeeeelllllllllo";
char[] chars = word.toCharArray();
Arrays.sort(chars); // sorted in ascending order
System.out.println(String.valueOf(chars));
```